# Roblox Studio: Attempt to index nil with 'Connect'

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I am doing a script and output says this " Workspace.Script:30: attempt to index nil with 'Connect' ". The error is on line 30 that has this code:

```
players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player) -- line 30

    if player.UserId == alertaCorUserId then
    alertaCorEvent:FireClient(player, true)
    else
    alertaCorEvent:FireClient(player, false)
    end

end)
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing are working. All help is welcome. I will put here the whole script

```
local players = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()

if #players > 0 then
    
    local alertaCorUserId = players[math.random(1, #players)].UserId

    
    local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
    local alertaCorEvent = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("AlertaCorEvent")

    if not alertaCorEvent then
        alertaCorEvent = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
        alertaCorEvent.Name = "AlertaCorEvent"
        alertaCorEvent.Parent = ReplicatedStorage
    end

    
    if alertaCorEvent then
        

        players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

            if player.UserId == alertaCorUserId then
                alertaCorEvent:FireClient(player, true)
            else
                alertaCorEvent:FireClient(player, false)
            end

        end)
        
        alertaCorEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, isAlertaCor)
            
            if isAlertaCor then
                print(player.Name .. " is Alerta Cor!")
                
            else
                print(player.Name .. " isn't Alerta Cor!")
                
            end
        end)
        
        
        
    else
        warn("Erro: alertaCorEvent is nil.")
    end
else
    warn("No players to be selected")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`game:GetService("Players")` is the player service, `game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()` is a table with all connected players. You want to connect an event to the service, not to that table.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I changed this and then put `local playerList = players:GetPlayers()` to be able to use it in math.random and now it's working. I really appreciate the help.